# Чи правильно «Вищий навчальний заклад»?

Tags: вибір-слова, словосполучення, прикметники

**Вищий навчальний заклад** — фактично русизм, але загальновживаний.

За логікою хіба не мало б бути **Найвищий навчальний заклад**?

Але жодної згадки в авторитетний джерелах не бачу. То як правильно і чому?

Comment: Добрий день. Чому ви думаєте, що це росіянізм? Є, наприклад, люди, які думають, що "учбовий" - це росіянізм. Але підтвердження у питанні немає. Чому має бути "найвищий"? За якою логікою? До речі, я вважаю, що "русизм" - це росіянізм, адже в українській мові немає "русского язика", у нас є "російська мова" або "Росія".

Comment: З одного боку, такі речі (_блаженніший_, _вищий_, _святіший_ тощо) цілком могли виникнути під впливом російської мови (де _блаженнейший_, _высший_, _святейший_ і т.ін. почали з часом означати найвищий (superlative) ступінь замість вищого (comparative)). Тобто інтуїтивно здається вірогідним, що тут мається на увазі найвищий (superlative) ступінь, але застосовуються прикметники вищого (comparative) ступеня, «бо так кажуть росіяни».

Comment: З іншого, конкретно [вища освіта](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Вища_освіта), наприклад, англійською [higher education](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_education). Можливо, первинно тут якраз мався на увазі саме вищий (comparative) ступінь. А вже сучасні люди помиляються, інтерпретуючи відповідні слова згідно з традиціями сучасної російської мови, а не часів виникнення цих термінів.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Джерело:** Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови (з дод. і допов.) 2005

> Вищий - вищий ступінь до високий. Форма якісного прикметника чи
> прислівника, що означає якість певного предмета, яка властива йому
> більшою мірою, ніж іншому.
>
> Освіта - Сукупність знань, здобутих у процесі навчання.

**Джерело:** Словниця української (або югової-руської) мови. Фортуната Піскунова. 1873

> Вищий - высшій.

**Джерело:** Українська граматика. 1917

> Міна шелестівок.
> 52. При збігу кількох шелестівок і на кінці слів. сш - щ (шч): кращий (крас-ший), товщий (товс(т) - ший), вищий.
>
> 174. Най-, прилучає ся до другого (вищого) ступеня прикметників і прислівників, щоб визначити найвищий ступінь: най-більший, най-кращий,
>      най-старший, най-дорожче.

**Джерело:** Український правопис. 2019

> § 20. Зміни приголосних у прикметниках і прислівниках вищого ступеня
> порівняння
>
> Під час творення прикметників і прислівників вищого ступеня
> порівняння г, ж, з змінюємо на жч, а с — на щ: дороги́й — доро́жчий
> (доро́жче); ду́жий — ду́жчий (ду́жче); вузьки́й — ву́жчий (ву́жче);
> низьки́й — ни́жчий (ни́жче); висо́кий — ви́щий (ви́ще), але: легки́й —
> ле́гший (ле́гше).

Не існує найвищого навчального закладу. Найвищої освіти. На сьогодні немає меж у освіти, тобто не існує "най-" для освіти.

А правильно тепер "Заклад вищої освіти".

[Джерело](https://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/2145-19)

> у тексті Закону слова "вищий навчальний заклад" і "вищий духовний
> навчальний заклад" в усіх відмінках і числах замінити відповідно
> словами "заклад вищої освіти" і "заклад вищої духовної освіти" у
> відповідному відмінку і числі;